# how can i exit nodejs script after mongo db write

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 400,000 lines to enter and I need to break it up.  Unfortunately I cannot get this script to exit until it's completed everything.  It invariably runs out of memory of course.  I thought setting a value at .on('end',function()  would be useful but I can't see that value once the .on data has completed.

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var done;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/auth');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  isActive: String,
  roles: {
    account: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Account'
    }
  },
  timeCreated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  search: [String]
});

var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  isVerified: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  verificationToken: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  name: {
    first: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    middle: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    last: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    full: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  company: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  memberid: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  status: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      ref: 'Status'
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    userCreated: {
      id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      },
      time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  },
  userCreated: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    time: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  },
  search: [String]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

fs.createReadStream('./ipart')
  .pipe(parse({
    delimiter: ','
  }))
  .on("data-invalid", function(data) {})
  .on('data', function(csvrow) {
    var u = {
      isActive: 'yes',
      username: csvrow[0],
      email: csvrow[0],
      search: [
        csvrow[1] + ' ' + csvrow[2],
        csvrow[0],
      ]
    };

    User.create(u, function(err, createdUser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      var user = createdUser;
      var displayName = csvrow[1] + ' ' + csvrow[2] || '';
      var nameParts = displayName.split(' ');
      var acct = {
        isVerified: 'no',
        'name.first': nameParts[0],
        'name.last': nameParts[1] || '',
        'name.full': displayName,
        user: {
          id: user._id,
          name: user.username
        },
        search: [
          nameParts[0],
          nameParts[1] || ''
        ]
      };

      Account.create(acct, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
          return workflow.emit('exception', err);
        }
        var fieldstoset = {
          roles: {
            account: account._id
          }
        };
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(account.user.id, fieldstoset, function(err, user) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      });
    });
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('complete');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use bulk inserts, I found this code somewhere and pasting it for you

```
         var Potato = mongoose.model('Potato', PotatoSchema);
         var potatoBag = [/* a humongous amount of potato objects */];
         Potato.collection.insert(potatoBag, onInsert);
         function onInsert(err, docs) {
           if (err) {
             // TODO: handle error
           } else {
             console.info('%d potatoes were successfully stored.', docs.length);
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to break down your entire logic of importing your CSV data into these following steps:
1. Write a simple script file which imports the CSV into a temporary collection like this:

> YourImportScript

```
#!/bin/bash 
mongoimport -d YourDBName -c YourTempCollectionName --drop --type csv --file pathToYourCSVFile.csv --headerline
```

2. Run the scripts before creating your Users:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function importCSV(callback) {
    exec("./pathToYourImportScript/YourImportScript", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        if (error !== null)
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        });

        callback()
    }
```

MongoImport will import the CSV pretty quickly.

3. Get the documents from the temp collection and insert them into your Users Collection.
   You can also use async module to control the flow of your code mode neatly:

> ```
> async.series([
>                     function (callback) {
>                       //CSV Import function 
>                     },
>                     function (callback) {
>         //User Manupulation function
>         }]);
> ```

And it is better to put headers into your CSV columns, as you can create a model when importing documents from the temp collections, and it would be easier to get the properties of users by column headers like `username:myCSVModel.username` instead of `username: csvrow[0]`.